# UITableView editing style may not show delete button

Tags: ios, uitableview, edit

Occasionally, when UITableView is in editing style and when you trigger the delete button, this button may not show. It seldom happen, but did anybody get the same issue too?

Post some code:

In viewDidLoad,

```
[[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

table view delegate:

```
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //do sth.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention how you are setting your tableview's editting mode . Put some code here .

Comment: Please add some code which u used to set editting mode for TableView.

Comment: If you can reproduce this under specific conditions or on a specific OS, you can raise this as a bug with Apple.

Comment: just edit, adding some code.